# How do you get the new top and left of a child div inside a rotated parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to use the new top and left of the child div inside a rotated parent to limit the draggable area of the rotated parent. Im using jquery draggable for this.

EDIT : 
Here is the `jsfiddle` . Im planning to use the red dot on the rotated div to use as marker to check if it collided with the boundaries of the container. I need to get the new position(top and left) of that red marker to make use of my ready made function to contain the draggable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate the `top` or `left` offset for any element, you need to use **[`.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)**, in addition to accounting for the **[window scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll)**.

This is also the case for rotated elements, as can be seen in the following example:

```js
function findTopLeft(element) {
  var rec = document.getElementById(element).getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    top: rec.top + window.scrollY,
    left: rec.left + window.scrollX
  };
}

console.log(findTopLeft('inner'));
```

```css
#outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">Text</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)